# Write a function of type: add a -> a -> a in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, lambda, functional-programming

I am looking for a javascript equivalent of how I would write out this function

Write a function of type: add  a ->  a -> a

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of functions with a type signature like `a -> a -> a`. Your question is too abstract and you didn't show any effort either. More like an exam question.

Type `a -> a -> a` mean you take two arguments with **any** data type. However, the arguments and the return data type must be the same. Is it clear?

By understanding this, you might be able to write a function such as `const add = (a, b) => a + b`. Suppose that `a` and `b` is an integer. Then, the result will be an integer as well. Another example is when `a` and `b` is a string. The result will be a string as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean something like

```
add a -> b -> a + b
```

Then assuming you are working in ES6 you could do that in a couple ways, including this:

```
const add = a => b => a + b;
```